# WCF and SingleWSDL - Cannot merge wsdls for imports

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, xsd, wsdl

At the moment we have a problem with WCF and generating a singleWsdl.

We have created a behavior which can add a Header to a wcf service.
This behavior named IncomingHeaderBehavior implements the IWsdlExportExtension and the ExportEndpoint method. This method loads the Header xsd and adds it to the wsdl. (code included as attachment).

Result:
The generated wsdl contains the header definitions shown below but the singleWsdl does not.

```
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://www.randomsite.nl/Header">
  <xsd:element name="Header">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element ref="rgh:HeaderVersion"/>
        <xsd:element ref="rgh:MessageId"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
  <xsd:element name="HeaderVersion">
    <xsd:annotation>
      <xsd:documentation>Version of the header</xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:simpleType>
      <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:simpleType>
  </xsd:element>
  <xsd:element name="MessageId">
    <xsd:annotation>
      <xsd:documentation>Id of the message</xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:simpleType>
      <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:maxLength value="30"/>
      </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
  </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

SoapUI generates the following request for the wsdl:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:head="http://www.randomsite.nl/Header" xmlns:ser="http://www.asite.com/Service1/">
  <soapenv:Header>
    <head:Header>
      <head:HeaderVersion>?</head:HeaderVersion>
      <head:MessageId>?</head:MessageId>
    </head:Header>
  </soapenv:Header>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <ser:GetData>
      <!--Optional:-->
      <ser:value>?</ser:value>
    </ser:GetData>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

As you can see, the fields HeaderVersion and MessageId are missing in the header for the SingleWSDL, but I don't know how to resolve this.

As attachment here are the relevant code snippets: [Complete code example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B39dypU6mRBWU09GV3A3S25rc2c/view?usp=sharing)

The behaviour extension:

```
    using System;
    using System.ServiceModel;
    using System.ServiceModel.Channels;
    using System.ServiceModel.Configuration;
    using System.ServiceModel.Description;
    using System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher;
    using System.Xml.Linq;

    namespace WcfHeaderBehaviorLibrary
    {
        public class IncomingHeaderBehavior : BehaviorExtensionElement, IDispatchMessageInspector, IEndpointBehavior, IWsdlExportExtension
        {
            public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
            {
            }

            public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
            {
                var messageHeaders = request.Headers;
                HeaderInput headerInput;

                try
                {
                    headerInput = messageHeaders.GetHeader<HeaderInput>("HeaderName", ServiceMetadata.HEADER_NAMESPACE);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    return null;
                }

                return headerInput;
            }

            public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
            {
            }

            public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
            {
                endpointDispatcher.DispatchRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(this);
            }

            public void BeforeSendReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
            {
                if (correlationState != null)
                {
                    var state = (HeaderInput)correlationState;

                    var headerInput = new HeaderInput
                    {
                        HeaderVersion = VersionService.HeaderVersion,
                        MessageId = state.MessageId,
                    };

                    var header = MessageHeader.CreateHeader("HeaderName", ServiceMetadata.HEADER_NAMESPACE, headerInput);
                    reply.Headers.Add(header);
                }
            }

            public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
            {
            }

            protected override object CreateBehavior()
            {
                return this;
            }

            public override Type BehaviorType
            {
                get { return GetType(); }
            }

            public void ExportContract(WsdlExporter exporter, WsdlContractConversionContext context)
            {
            }

            public void ExportEndpoint(WsdlExporter exporter, WsdlEndpointConversionContext context)
            {
                IncomingWsdlExport.ExportEndpoint(exporter, context);
            }
        }
    }
```

The WSDLExport class:

```
    using System;
    using System.Reflection;
    using System.ServiceModel.Description;
    using System.Web.Services.Description;
    using System.Xml;
    using System.Xml.Schema;
    using ServiceDescription = System.Web.Services.Description.ServiceDescription;

    namespace WcfHeaderBehaviorLibrary
    {
        public class IncomingWsdlExport
        {
            public static void ExportEndpoint(WsdlExporter exporter, WsdlEndpointConversionContext context)
            {
                var headerXsd = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("WcfHeaderBehaviorLibrary.xsd.Header.xsd");
                var customSoapHeaderSchema = XmlSchema.Read(headerXsd, ValidationCallBack);

                var headerMessage = CreateHeaderMessage(customSoapHeaderSchema);

                foreach (ServiceDescription wsdl in exporter.GeneratedWsdlDocuments)
                {
                    wsdl.Types.Schemas.Add(customSoapHeaderSchema);
                    wsdl.Namespaces.Add("rgh", customSoapHeaderSchema.TargetNamespace);
                    wsdl.Messages.Add(headerMessage);
                }

                AddHeaderToOperations(headerMessage, context);
            }

            private static Message CreateHeaderMessage(XmlSchema customSoapHeaderSchema)
            {
                var headerMessage = new Message { Name = "Header" };

                var part = new MessagePart
                {
                    Name = "header",
                    Element = new XmlQualifiedName("Header", customSoapHeaderSchema.TargetNamespace)
                };

                headerMessage.Parts.Add(part);

                return headerMessage;
            }

            private static void AddHeaderToOperations(Message headerMessage, WsdlEndpointConversionContext context)
            {
                var header = new XmlQualifiedName(headerMessage.Name, headerMessage.ServiceDescription.TargetNamespace);

                foreach (OperationBinding operation in context.WsdlBinding.Operations)
                {
                    ExportMessageHeaderBinding(operation.Input, header, false);
                    ExportMessageHeaderBinding(operation.Output, header, false);
                }
            }

            private static void ExportMessageHeaderBinding(MessageBinding messageBinding, XmlQualifiedName header, bool isEncoded)
            {
                var binding = new Soap12HeaderBinding
                {
                    Part = "header", 
                    Message = header, 
                    Use = isEncoded ? SoapBindingUse.Encoded : SoapBindingUse.Literal
                };

                messageBinding.Extensions.Add(binding);
            }

            private static void ValidationCallBack(object sender, ValidationEventArgs args)
            {
                if (args.Severity == XmlSeverityType.Warning)
                    Console.WriteLine("\tWarning: Matching schema not found. No validation occurred." + args.Message);
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("\tValidation error: " + args.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```